# I am just trying to get my code to compile properly

Tags: c++

I am not too well-versed in utilising classes. I usually can use classes with a lowercase, but with an uppercase, I don't understand why it won't compile.

My code is three files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

animal.h:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Animal
{
    public:
        Animal(std::string aSpecies);
        void set_name(std::string aName);

        std::string get_species();
        std::string get_name();
        int get_ID();

        int id_num;
        std::string name;
};

#endif
```

animal.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"
//using namespace std;

Animal::Animal()
{
    id_num = 0;
    name = 0;
}

Animal(std::string aSpecies)
{

}

void Animal::set_name(std::string aName)
{

}

std::string Animal::get_species()
{

}

std::string Animal::get_name()
{

}

int get_ID()
{

}
```

Right now, it will not print anything, I just want it to compile without errors.

The errors are:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
animal.h:9:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘aSpecies’
         Animal(string aSpecies);
                       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from animal.cpp:2:0:
animal.h:9:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘aSpecies’
         Animal(string aSpecies);
                       ^~~~~~~~
animal.cpp:5:16: error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘Animal::Animal()’
 Animal::Animal()
                ^
animal.cpp:11:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘aSpecies’
 Animal(std::string aSpecies)
                    ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: And the errors are...?

Comment: can you add the compiler error?

Comment: Yes sorry, I was in a rush! I just added the errors. Thank you!

Comment: You need `#include <string>` to use `std::string`.

Comment: I was able to figure out the error, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor `Animal::Animal()` is not defined in class. Add `Animal();` to class definition.

Replace `Animal(std::string aSpecies)` with `Animal::Animal(std::string aSpecies)` in implementation (animal.cpp).

Add `#include <string>` to `animal.h` to work with string.